# You have reached your question limit

Tags: discussion, support

What? Have a question similar to [Home on the Range of Lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/home-on-the-range-of-lists).

Why cannot this user ask the question?

---

Does that mean that even if the question is posted at Sandbox and well-received that the question will still not be posted at the main site?

Comment: Could you quote or screenshot the complete error message you get?

Comment: @Dennis _"You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."_ Full disclosure: Have encountered this issue previously at another SE site [What is the rationale for the “question ban” for user guest271314?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3504/21216), though the subject matter and topic range there could be considered by nature contentious. There is apparently an "algorithm" that SE employs. Not sure how such an "algorithm" is remotely related to the subject matter and topics at PPCG.

Comment: Possible someone as the normal questions forget to specify error cases, and limits cases...

Comment: @RosLuP Not sure what you mean? That the questions asked did not specify error cases and limit cases?

Answer (score 6):

The Stack Exchange software imposes a temporary question ban on users who meet a threshold for low-quality questions, determined by the number of questions closed, deleted, and/or having a negative score in a given period of time. You met that threshold, and the system imposed the ban. There's nothing that can be done to remove it, other than just waiting for the ban to expire.

See [the help center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) for more information.

Comment: @guest271314 We should continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88066/discussion-between-guest271314-and-hyperneutrino). (Sorry Mego).

Comment: @guest271314 OK, that's enough. It's one thing to ask for support for your question ban, but it's another thing entirely to start ranting about employees or other users across the network. If you have a problem with how this site works, you're welcome to [contact the employees](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) or discontinue your use of this site. But starting a witch hunt that's completely unrelated to the automatic question ban is unproductive and will not be tolerated.